# What am I doing wrong in this price calculator?

Tags: java, calculator

I can't get the output to give any number beside 0.0 What am I doing wrong here?

```
int num1 = 0;    
double d1 = 3.25, d2 = 0.45;
double numdozen = num1 / 12;
double numlooseeggs = num1 - (numdozen * 12);
double totaldozen = numdozen;
double totalloose = numlooseeggs;

Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many eggs do you want? They are $3.25/dozen or $.45/egg.");
num1 = fromKeyboard.nextInt();



double sum = totaldozen + totalloose;

System.out.println("$" + sum);
```

Comment: Do the calculations after you get num1 from the keyboard

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please make your question easy to understand for others. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @afzalex His question is pretty clear to me.

Comment: So sad that this awesome website became the place for doing others homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double numdozen = num1 / 12;`

This initializes `numdozen` to 0.0, which probably wasn't your intent (if it was your intent, you would simply set it to 0.0).

`numlooseeggs` is also initialized to 0.0, as well as `totaldozen` and `totalloose`.

I don't think you intended all of them to be 0.

Finally `double sum = totaldozen + totalloose;` is set to 0, regardless of what you assign to `num1`.

What you probably want to do is calculate the non constant doubles after getting the user input :

```
num1 = fromKeyboard.nextInt();
double numdozen = (double)num1 / 12;
double numlooseeggs = num1 - (numdozen * 12);
double totaldozen = numdozen;
double totalloose = numlooseeggs;
```

Note that you should cast `num1` to double before dividing it by 12, or `numdozen` would be 0 if num1 < 12.

Comment: Commenting just since the terms weren't explicitly used in this answer, but it might be worth the OP reading through some literature on reference and value types. I just found this related question in a quick search. It's not exactly the same matter, but given that this was a problem, I'm guessing reading here will help with future ones too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Thank you so much! My professor told us there was a way to initialize an int before getting user input and still return the correct output but I've been trying to wrap my head around this all weekend and you made more sense than he did

Answer (score 1):

you are seting everything to nothing

```
int num1 = 0;                                    0

double d1 = 3.25, d2 = 0.45;

double numdozen = num1 / 12;                     0 / 12 = 0
double numlooseeggs = num1 - (numdozen * 12);    0 - (0 * 12) = 0
double totaldozen = numdozen;                    0
double totalloose = numlooseeggs;                0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating all your values before you take the user input, so `num1` is `0`, forcing everything else to be `0`. Put the calculations *after* you take input, like this:

```
int num1 = 0;
// don't do calculations that depend on input yet

Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many eggs do you want? They are $3.25/dozen or $.45/egg.");
num1 = fromKeyboard.nextInt();

// put the calculations that depend on input here
double d1 = 3.25, d2 = 0.45;
double numdozen = num1 / 12.0;
double numlooseeggs = num1 - (numdozen * 12);
double totaldozen = numdozen;
double totalloose = numlooseeggs;

double sum = totaldozen + totalloose;

System.out.println("$" + sum);
```